# How to create htpasswd blank user

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

How to create a `htpasswd` file that allows the enter with blank username and password.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "User"
AuthUserFile "/home/passwd"
!require valid-user
```

Comment: Why bother? Just leave it annoymous

Comment: @PanamaJack i want to block DDoS attack with this trick

Comment: So any connection is required to press enter in order to access (which a network stresser can't do)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I personally would use a module that mitigates DOS attacks better than that solution. I've used them for DOS/Brute Force attacks at my previous jobs and they were very affective.

One such mod is [mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/)

However if you really want to present an authentication box to them without credentials you have to enable `mod_authn_anon`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_anon.html

Then you can use the `Anonymous_NoUserID` directive to be able to provide an empty userid and/or password. Then they can just hit enter. You can get more info at the following link.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_anon.html#anonymous_nouserid

Comment: Yea i got to that documentation while searching but i can't get it to work, can you post a code snippet ?

Comment: A working .htaccess example would be:

`AuthName "Please login..."`
`AuthType Basic`
`AuthBasicProvider anon`

`Anonymous_NoUserID on`
`Anonymous_MustGiveEmail off`
`Anonymous guest`

`Require valid-user`